# how to detect if java installed in my computer from javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, applet, jnlp

I want to detect if java installed in my computer from javascript , so that in case java is not installed on the user machine , then he can be notified that there is no java on your computer so you must first install java in your computer then only you should download the jnlp file from our website .

Please note that the solution shuould work on all browsers .

Things i have already tried :

1. `navigator.javaEnabled()` is not solving the problem as it is for detecting the java in the browser , which i don't want as i want to detect java in my computer(some users computer on client machine)
2. `JavaWebToolKit(deployJava.js)` , i have already checked this js , methods in this js to detect `JAVA VERSION` and java are not working on all browsers , moreover it will return true even when java is not installed .
3. using commandline cmd to check the value for `JAVA_HOME` and `java -version` , this will not work in case java is installed but classpath is not set
4. running applets to run check for java will not work , as applet support is removed from java future versions , though we can still use JNLPs

Comment: You can't detect if java is installed on a computer. With javascript you can only detect if java is installed on the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's a losing battle these days. One of the best solutions used to be this one:

http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Java/

But that uses an Applet. And with NPAPI now deprecated, and already dropped from Chrome, it's only a matter of time before it becomes more work than benefit to try.

Your best bet is probably to base around WebStart, include a warning note 1st time to users that they must have Java installed, and then if launch fails at least they know where to look.